# Comparing access time of a char array vs uint8_t array vs int8_t array

Tags: c

I've observed that accessing a data item in a char array takes a lot less time that accessing a data item in an int array. I am guessing that it happens because the size of ints is larger than that of chars as such the "memory controller" (the thing which controls memory in C -I don't know the technical term) has to move a larger distance.

uint8_t char and int8_t have the same size. So storing data in an array of which data type will give the fastest access time.?

I had created a program to store 150000 words in a hashtable of size 250000 buckets. When the data type of the hashtable array was int, the load time was .16 seconds, but when the data type was char or uint8 or int8, the load time varied between .08 to .11 seconds. So my test was inconclusive

Comment: Could you give us some code and test results please?

Comment: You should know that `int8_t` and `uint8_t` are usually derived from `signed char` and `unsigned char`, respectively. Now think again if access times may be different.

Comment: why not write a test

Comment: This is **entirely** platform-dependent. Often times, a lookup into a `char` array involves reading 64/128 bits and selecting the specified `char` out of it. With caching, this may wind up fetching 32 *bytes* at a time. Same thing happens when indexing an `int` array.

Comment: Give us concrete proof that accessing `char` is faster than `int`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answer to this.

It's 100% dependent upon your hardware, your compiler, OS, mains voltage, and phase of the moon. At least some of those.

C doesn't specify things at that level.

On a typical (modern) computer with byte-addressable memory, `char` will be 8 bits ("a byte"). It will then mean that `uint8_t` will be an alias for `unsigned char`, and `int8_t` will be `signed char`.

Thus, access times for `uint8_t`, `int8_t` and `char` will be the same, since they're all essentially the same type just with different sign semantics.